# ADAL and OAuth Assertion flow

Tags: adal

does AAD support the oauth assertion flow (rfc 6749 extentions grants) ? can't find any examples, so I assume this is not implemented in ADAL nor supported by AAD..... yet or ?

cheers Allan

Answer (score 4):

AAD supports both the assertion grant type as well as the client_assertion grant type.

In the assertion grant type the following assertion types are supported:

- urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml1_1-bearer
- urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer

There is also a urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer assertion type.  However, this assertion type is only used to obtain an access token for a downstream service, from an access token presented by a native client.  (See here for an example: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet)

ADAL.NET exposes the assertion grant type through AcquireToken methods that take a UserAssertion object.

The client_assertion flow is for authenticating a server and it can be accessed through AcquireToken methods that take a ClientAssertion object.

For an example of using the client assertion flow see this example:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/Daemon-CertificateCredential-DotNet

And of course the ADAL .NET implementation code resides here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet

Comment: hi Rich, no this one is on me, I should have been more clear here. What I am looking for here is a *federation* scenario where the assertion flow is used. btw. the jwt-bearer assertion type it not restricted for downservices here, that depends on what AAD1 issues initially. regards Allan